# CSS Third Level Dropdown Menu Issue

Tags: css, menu

I have a CSS dropdown menu implemented based on http://jsfiddle.net/2RgmH/

Currently I have a problem where in the 3rd level menu items are not alligned with
their second level parent. The 3rd level block starts one level below.

My CSS:

```
* {
     list-style:none;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     font-size:1em;
     cursor:pointer;
  }
#menu{
     margin:3px;
}

#menu > li{            /* Top Level */
    float:left;
    margin-right:3px;
}
#menu > li > span{
    display:block;
    background:#55aa7f;
    padding:3px 10px;
}
#menu > li:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
}

#menu > li > ul{        /* Second Level */
    display:none;
    background:#55aa7f;
}
#menu > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
#menu > li > ul > li > span{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-top:solid 3px #fff;
}
#menu > li > ul > li:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
}

#menu > li > ul li > ul{   /* Third Level & beyond */
    display:none;
    background:#55aa7f;
}
#menu > li > ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    border-left:solid 3px #fff;
    top:0;
    width:auto;
}
#menu > li > ul > li ul > li{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-top:solid 3px #fff;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#menu > li > ul > li ul > li:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML is

```
<li><span>Home</span></li>
<li><span>Test-L1</span>
<ul>
    <li><span>Test-L2A</span></li>
    <li><span>Test-L2B</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Test-L3A</span></li>
            <li><span>Test-L3B</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Test-L2C</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Test-L3C</span></li>
            <li><span>Test-L3D</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I found a question with identical problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293625/third-level-css-dropdown)
I did try to implement the only answer given there. But couldnt make it work.
Could some one help me with actual CSS portion for the 3rd level menu alignment with their parent.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue you described in Chrome, but it might be helpful to add a mockup of what it should look like so we can better assist.

Comment: works fine on chrome.

Comment: which browser are you using? works fine on Chrome.

Comment: You can change top:0 value in #menu > li > ul li:hover > ul{

Comment: Move the mouse to Test-L2B.Menu List Test-L3A and Test-L3B does show up but I want Test-L3A at same level as Test-L2B.
Similarly move mouse around Test-L2C. Child Test-L3C is at the level of second level parent Test-L2A.In general any 3rd level block starts at top and not at their corresponding parent.
I used IE9 and also Chrome version 29.0.1547.66 m. In both case same behaviour I described above.If I change Top:1 in #menu > li > ul li:hover > ul{,then the blocks come down and stay one level below their parent.Seems I need variable offset.Any hints? Still dont know how it work for some of you

Comment: Could some one help me in identify the current mouse pointed element and its position. I found that in my case problem will solved if proper value for 'top' is give under #menu > li > ul li:hover > ul{ . But it should be relative to the 2nd level menu selected. I plan to get the second level parent index/postion and add offset to set the position for 3rd level child block. Please help me in this.