# CSS Dropdown menu -Get parent index/postion

Tags: css, submenu

I have CSS dropdown menu in which  I have problem displaying 3rd level submenu. I have already submitted the question [CSS Third Level Dropdown Menu Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686499/css-third-level-dropdown-menu-issue)
Now I am planning a alternative just to solve the problem. 
I have the relevant portion of css here

```
#menu > li > ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    border-left:solid 3px #fff;
    top:0;
    width:auto;
}
```

The top attribute above describes the top of 3rd lvel block. I want to dynamicaly add postion of parent (2nd level) so that I get the allignment right. 
Some thing like

```
top: x+current_parent_position
```

or

```
top: x+current_parent_index * menu_height
```

Please guide me about getting the position or top property of parent menu item.

Comment: you cannot use computational values in CSS, if there is no way to statically set the position (i.e. the 3rd level menu should always be at X/Y position), then you need javascript to do it for you. A jsfiddle of what you have so far, would go a long way to getting some help, it's the standard thing to do when asking for help with visuals

Comment: 1. Do you have a fiddle? 2. You don't have to use absolute positioning. There are probably better options

Comment: Thank you both for pointing at creating jfiddle code.I was unaware that we can create our own jfiddle.I have created jfiddle and posted the question and got solution as well. Thanks.